# How to fix 'javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError on every second server startup'

Tags: java, jaxb, glassfish, classloader

I'm writing a web application which uses JAXB and JAX-RS. The content-type used for getting/sending data to the server is XML. The web application runs in a GlassFish server(4.1.2/ 5), the JDK used is 1.8.

The problem is that the internal SAXParser allows doctype declarations which makes XEE-Attacks possible. I'm not able to inject the specific feature into the SAXParserFactory, so i built a wrapper for the SAXParserFactory, which sets the feature. The SAXParserFactory is registered using the system properties.

`System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory","de.mycompany.sdk.parser.SAXParserFactoryWrapper");`

Unfortunately, the server throws a ClassNotFoundException on every **second** startup, otherwise the application behaves normal.
Has anyone ideas how to fix it?

I've also tried to include the jar into the class path or specify it using the manifest, but did not work neither.

I get the following error:

````
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider de.mycompany.sdk.parser.SAXParserFactoryWrapper not found
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:200)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:152)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:232)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.getSAXParser(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:125)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de/mycompany/sdk/parser/SAXParserFactoryWrapper
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:124)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:188)
    ... 56 more```
````

Comment: But "de.mycompany.sdk.parser.SAXParserFactoryWrapper" is included in your web archive that you deploy?

Comment: Yes, i included the sdk into the pom of the web service with ```<type>jar</type>``` and the build process builds a war package

Comment: Could you please verify that the deployed WAR contains the desired JAR in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: And where do you actually set that System property?? How do you ensure that your class has been loaded before the System property is read? Maybe you could try to add the `SAXParserFactoryWrapper` as a library to Glassfish. That should ensure that it gets picked up early.   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/add-library.htm#GSRFM00818

Answer (score 0):

*ClassNotFoundException*
can occur if you have multiple versions of a class (de.mycompany.sdk.parser.SAXParserFactoryWrapper in this case) in your class path. This generally happens when you have multiple versions of the same library in your classpath.

Comment: I separated the SAXParserFactoryWrapper into an additional project and included it again, unfortunately the ClassNotFoundException still occurs exactly every second start up :/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! I found a solution for my problem. I deployed the application using the GlassFish CLI and it works! The previous tries were done using NetBeans. It seems that NetBeans does anything different during the startup or shutdown process of the GlassFish server wich involves the exception.